# calculate value of a column for a row when data in same row is added to another column

Tags: python, pandas, moving-average

I have a large pandas data frame in python. I have seven columns of raw data that get updated all at once on a periodic basis, and I need to update the values in the new rows of the 84 other columns every time new data is added to the bottom of columns 1-7. I would like to do this without having to recalculate all the values of the entire 84 other columns. as there are millions of rows in these columns.

Comment: Your question seems interesting but I could not understand it. Is it possible to show an example?

Comment: For Example, I start with the following data frame:

Comment: TP1df = pd.DataFrame({'c1':[],'c2':[],'c3':[],'c4':[],'c5':[],'c6':[],'c7':[]})

Comment: Then I run: TP1df = pd.read_csv(f'C:/filelocation_{x}#{y}.csv', delimiter=',',names = ['c1','c2','c3','c4','c5','c6','c7'])

Comment: to load in some raw data., then I run a about 84 caluclations and create 84 new columns in the data frame based on those calculations

Comment: so say at this point there are 91 columns on 1 million rows.

Comment: then on a periodic basis I add new "raw data" to columns 1-7

Comment: then if I run the same code to calculate the new missing data for say row 1million and 1, it currently recalculates all of the informatoin in rows 1 to 1million.

Comment: (for column 8-91) where as I just want to calculate the new value located at row 1,000,001 column 9, not all of column 9 again, the previous data does not change based on new data

Comment: Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to write an answer for you.

Comment: You could restrict your dataframe to the last row after the update, and then run your calculations. df.iloc[:-1, :]

Comment: I am working with moving averages, so I need to be able to access all of the information in previous rows for columns 1-7

Comment: here is an example of: a line that calculates on the entire column: TP1df[f'y{var}_{i}z'] = TP1df['c1'].ewm(span=var*i).mean()

Comment: This is calculating an exponential weighted moving average for the entire column. I just want to do this by the row, for a column as new data is added to columns 1-7

Comment: .ewm is from the talib library. (technical analysis library, mainly used for financial analysis)

Answer (score 0):

After doing the first calculation on the main dataframe, try doing the calculation for new data separately then concat them at the end (provided both have the same columns before concatenation).

```py
import pandas as pd

columns = ['c1','c2','c3','c4','c5','c6','c7']

main = pd.read_csv('file.csv', names=columns)
# ... do your calculation

new = pd.read_csv('new_file.csv', names=columns)
# ... do your calculation

all = pd.concat([main, new])

# if you need to reset the index, use the following line instead:
# all = pd.concat([main, new], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: I am calculating moving averages, so this will not suffice, the calculations in the new rows for columns 8-91, have to be able to work with all of the data in the previous rows for columns 1-7